# How to do a string to long int?

Tags: c, string, long-integer

I want to create a function to take a string like this `"2014-02-13T06:20:00"`

and to convert to a `long long int` like `20140213062000`.

Has anyone a idea how this can be done?

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? Do you know how to for example convert a string `"2014-02"` to `"201402"`? Do you know anything about strings in C?

Comment: @KamilCuk I try with strtoll and strtol but the output is only 2014

Comment: Did you expect `strtol` to convert or omit `-` in the string? What do you think you have to do with the `-` in the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an algorithm, you will just write the code:

- define a `long long` variable `n` and initialize it to `0`.
- for each character `c` in the string:

  - if `c` is a digit, ie greater or equal to `'0'` and less or equal to `'9'`:
  - multiply `n` by `10` and add the value represented by `c`, store the result in `n`.
  - else:
  - ignore the non digit character
- `n` should have the expected value.

This would convert positive values. If the string has an initial `-` indicating a negative number, you would test that and negate the number at the end.  Note also that overflowing the range of `long long int` has undefined behavior with this approach.

Your attempt in the comment needs some improvements:

```
long long string_To_long(const char sl[]) {
    long long int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; sl[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char c = sl[i];
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, parse the string, copy the relevant parts to a temporary string, then call strtoul on that one. `char tmp[14+1] = { [0]=str[0], [1]=str[1], ...}; ... return strtoul(tmp, NULL, 10);`

Comment: @Lundin: this approach requires making an assumption on the string length and format. I would suggest `strtoll` or `strtoull` in this case.

Comment: @user1555: using an `int` index `i` and a `char *s`, `s[i]` is the n-th character of the string. You would stop the scan when `s[i] == 0`. I suggest getting a real course in C.

Comment: @user1555 almost there: there is no need to make a copy of the string argument and this `strcpy` would have undefined behavior if that string has more than 18 characters. The digit value is `sk[i] - '0'`, and you must return `n` at the end.